# Re-creating/matching ffmpeg settings

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I have an MP4 file that plays pretty much on every browser using either HTML5 or flash fallback (using mediaelement.js).  I also have a series of additional video files that I would like to have "match" the one file that does play consistently but I haven't been able to match the ffmpeg settings so it produces a like file.  I used ffprobe and got the following results on the file that plays successfully:

```
ffprobe version N-53616-g7a2edcf Copyright (c) 2007-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on May 29 2013 01:21:08 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
 libavutil      52. 34.100 / 52. 34.100
 libavcodec     55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
 libavformat    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
 libavdevice    55.  1.101 / 55.  1.101
 libavfilter     3. 72.100 /  3. 72.100
 libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
 libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
 libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'MyFile.mp4':
 Metadata:
  major_brand     : M4V
  minor_version   : 1
  compatible_brands: M4V mp42isom
  creation_time   : 2013-05-29 16:08:29
Duration: 00:01:58.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1155 kb/s
 Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 995 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-05-29 16:08:29
  handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 157 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-05-29 16:08:29
  handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
```

Following a few guides I found online, I am using the following ffmpeg settings:

```
ffmpeg -i {input file name} -y -acodec aac -ac 2 -strict experimental -ab 64k -s 320x240 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset slow -profile:v baseline -level 30 -maxrate 300k -bufsize 600k -b:v 300k -f mp4 -threads 0 -movflags +faststart {output file name}
```

That command produces the following output:

```
ffmpeg -i "testin.mp4" -y -acodec aac -ac 2 -strict experimental -ab 64k -s 320x240 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset slow-profile:v baseline -level 30 -maxrate 300k -bufsize 600k -b:v 300k -f mp4 -threads 0 -movflags +faststart testout.mp4

ffmpeg version N-53616-g7a2edcf Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers  built on May 29 2013 01:21:08 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 34.100 / 52. 34.100
  libavcodec     55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
  libavformat    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
  libavdevice    55.  1.101 / 55.  1.101
  libavfilter     3. 72.100 /  3. 72.100
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'testin.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2013-10-01 17:11:42
  Duration: 00:04:33.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 725 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 596 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-01 17:11:42
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-01 17:11:42
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2AVX
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] 264 - core 133 r2334 a3ac64b - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=umh subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=50 rc=cbr mbtree=1 bitrate=300 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=300 vbv_bufsize=600 nal_hrd=none ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00

Output #0, mp4, to 'testout.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.7.100
   Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 300 kb/s, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-01 17:11:42
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-01 17:11:42
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  283 fps=0.0 q=21.0 size=     329kB time=00:00:09.30 bitrate= 289.9kbits/
frame=  565 fps=564 q=20.0 size=     760kB time=00:00:18.64 bitrate= 333.7kbits/
frame=  846 fps=564 q=21.0 size=    1179kB time=00:00:28.20 bitrate= 342.5kbits/
frame= 1123 fps=561 q=22.0 size=    1603kB time=00:00:37.33 bitrate= 351.7kbits/
frame= 1376 fps=550 q=25.0 size=    1986kB time=00:00:45.69 bitrate= 356.1kbits/
frame= 1651 fps=550 q=22.0 size=    2377kB time=00:00:55.01 bitrate= 353.9kbits/
frame= 1914 fps=546 q=24.0 size=    2776kB time=00:01:03.70 bitrate= 357.0kbits/
frame= 2181 fps=545 q=24.0 size=    3163kB time=00:01:12.70 bitrate= 356.4kbits/
frame= 2443 fps=543 q=24.0 size=    3566kB time=00:01:21.38 bitrate= 358.9kbits/
frame= 2702 fps=540 q=24.0 size=    3939kB time=00:01:30.04 bitrate= 358.4kbits/
frame= 2965 fps=539 q=24.0 size=    4338kB time=00:01:38.73 bitrate= 359.9kbits/
frame= 3236 fps=539 q=23.0 size=    4731kB time=00:01:48.03 bitrate= 358.7kbits/
frame= 3505 fps=539 q=24.0 size=    5130kB time=00:01:56.75 bitrate= 360.0kbits/
frame= 3765 fps=537 q=26.0 size=    5521kB time=00:02:05.41 bitrate= 360.6kbits/
frame= 4036 fps=538 q=24.0 size=    5905kB time=00:02:14.59 bitrate= 359.4kbits/
frame= 4326 fps=540 q=24.0 size=    6343kB time=00:02:24.10 bitrate= 360.6kbits/
frame= 4606 fps=542 q=27.0 size=    6783kB time=00:02:33.49 bitrate= 362.0kbits/
frame= 4886 fps=543 q=24.0 size=    7168kB time=00:02:42.81 bitrate= 360.7kbits/
frame= 5166 fps=544 q=27.0 size=    7616kB time=00:02:52.13 bitrate= 362.5kbits/
frame= 5456 fps=545 q=24.0 size=    8020kB time=00:03:01.84 bitrate= 361.3kbits/
frame= 5736 fps=546 q=27.0 size=    8458kB time=00:03:11.18 bitrate= 362.4kbits/
frame= 6001 fps=545 q=30.0 size=    8849kB time=00:03:20.17 bitrate= 362.1kbits/
frame= 6264 fps=544 q=27.0 size=    9233kB time=00:03:28.85 bitrate= 362.2kbits/
frame= 6526 fps=544 q=26.0 size=    9611kB time=00:03:37.55 bitrate= 361.9kbits/
frame= 6793 fps=543 q=26.0 size=   10006kB time=00:03:46.51 bitrate= 361.9kbits/
frame= 7076 fps=544 q=24.0 size=   10410kB time=00:03:55.86 bitrate= 361.6kbits/
frame= 7355 fps=544 q=25.0 size=   10835kB time=00:04:05.20 bitrate= 362.0kbits/
frame= 7615 fps=543 q=27.0 size=   11236kB time=00:04:13.88 bitrate= 362.5kbits/
frame= 7883 fps=543 q=25.0 size=   11625kB time=00:04:22.89 bitrate= 362.3kbits/
frame= 8166 fps=544 q=21.0 size=   12040kB time=00:04:32.31 bitrate= 362.2kbits/
Starting second pass: moving header on top of the file
frame= 8203 fps=540 q=-1.0 Lsize=   12417kB time=00:04:33.74 bitrate= 371.6kbits/s
video:10035kB audio:2150kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.901929%
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] frame I:41    Avg QP:14.13  size: 18349
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] frame P:8162  Avg QP:17.24  size:  1167
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] mb I  I16..4: 24.8%  0.0% 75.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  0.0%  0.3%  P16..4: 29.1%  6.4%  3.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:60.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 66.1% 74.1% 53.1% inter: 15.3% 20.2% 4.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] i16 v,h,dc,p: 23% 21% 11% 45%
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 25% 14%  6%  7% 7%  7%  6%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] i8c dc,h,v,p: 43% 28% 19% 10%
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] ref P L0: 78.4% 12.6%  4.9%  2.4%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000000358160] kb/s:300.33
```

The one problem with the incantation above is that on iPad's and iPhones and some Android tablets all you hear is the audio with no video.  But the file listed above (contents of the ffprobe) does not have that problem, it WILL play on an iPad, iPhone, Android tablet.  I researched causes for "audio, no video" and the recommendations were all over the deck. But, the file listed in the ffprobe DOES play, so if I can match those settings described by the ffprobe for all of the other videos, they should play consistently as well. My challenge is to match the ffprobe settings using ffmpeg and there doesn't seem to be a 1 to 1 match between what I see in ffprobe and the corresponding settings in ffmpeg (a nice utility would be to have ffprobe output the ffmpeg settings that could be used to create a file of similar format).

I walked through the ffprobe documentation but couldn't find anything that would produce a format that could be used as input to ffmpeg.  Suggestions?

Comment: I didn't know that there was YASEF (Yet Another StackExchange Forum) to post to.  Naturally posted here because I am dealing with a programming issue delivering video content to a browser.  ffprobe was just a tool to help me sort out the issues...thanks

Comment: You need to include the complete ffmpeg console output that goes with your ffmpeg command.

Comment: I hope I have it all now...it was only ffprobe that I ran.

Comment: You show a ffmpeg command but you did not show the console output from that command. That is more important than the ffprobe info.

Comment: So, if I understand the meaning behind your statement, then the ffprobe information is worthless in trying to create an ffmpeg command that will produce an output of similar format?  My goal is:

I have a file that works the way I want.  ffprobe can display the characteristics of that file.  I want to use the ffprobe information to create an ffmpeg command that produces a file of the same format.

Is the answer: "There is no way to use ffprobe information to create an ffmpeg command that will produce similar output"?  I'll post the ffmpeg console output but I am not sure it will help

Comment: The ffprobe output is useful, but the ffmpeg command and its output are just as important. You have files that do play as expected and these are described with the ffprobe output, but there is no info provided on the files you are attempting to create other than the command itself.

Comment: Hopefully the output will point to whatever is causing the video not to display on iPads, iPhones and some Android devices.

Comment: I am usually using the raw output of the MediaInfo utility to compare videos.  
Just an idea here: `major_brand     : mp42` although I have already seen this in good MP4 files, an M4V fourcc has more chances to be compatible with ios devices.

Comment: I have looked at the MediaInfo output as well.  The issue here is reading the output from either MediaInfo or ffprobe and figuring out what ffmpeg command line parameters to use to recreate the same type of file. So in your example, what ffmpeg parameter leads to the "major_brand" in the output?

Answer (score 5):

This ended up being solved by trial and error rather than finding a resource that would help me map ffprobe (or MediaInfo) output to ffmpeg parameters.  The final incantation that seems to work across browsers and devices that support mp4 video is:

ffmpeg -i {input file name} -codec:v libx264 -profile:v main -preset slow -b:v 300k -maxrate 300k -bufsize 600k -vf scale=320:-1  -threads 0 -acodec aac -ac 2 -strict experimental -ab 64k -y {output file name}

I need to wade through the ffmpeg documentation more thoroughly at some point because there are a bunch of knobs and levers to push and pull in that software but for now, this takes care of the immediate issue (I'd love to find a tool that would use ffprobe output to create an ffmpeg command that would produce a file of similar type though).